# What is the difference between POST and PATCH verbs and when would I use the former over the latter?

Tags: http, web

I'm reading up on the PATCH HTTP verb that was introduced in 2010 by rfc5789. It looks like it does exactly what POST verb does. In what case would I strongly prefer to use PATCH over POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use POST, for the simple reason that POST is the generic method in HTTP that can do anything.

PATCH has the advantage of being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` is used to create a resource (and for many other things).

`PUT` is used to update or create a resource.

`PATCH` is used to update *partially* a resource.

I don't think you would ever use `PATCH` in place of `POST`, however you could use it in place of `PUT` if you are making a partial update (and your server support it).

Also, see http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/

Comment: Without PATCH, the only obvious way for partial updates is POST, not PUT.

Comment: PUT usually also means to replace the resource completely.

Comment: @poke: agreed. Although I have seen implementations where absent fields in a put request are simply ignored. (which is wrong, this is typically a case where PATCH should have been used.)